# Error 500 when drag & drop an image via tinymce

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, tinymce

I have two domains pointing to the same joomla 3 : example1.com (main domain) and example2.com.
When I edit an article in front via the main domain, the drag & drop of an image works well with TinyMCE. When I connect from example2.com, I get an error 500 :

Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Document::addCustomTag()
on this url: https://exemple2.com/fr/?option=com_media&task=file.upload&tmpl=component&xxxxxxxxxxxxxx=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=1&asset=image&format=json

[image]

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938

Comment: I didn't know you could set up 2 domains, but was reading about it at https://docs.joomla.org/Multiple_Domains_and_Web_Sites_in_a_single_Joomla!_installation. Of the options described there, how have you configured your site? TinyMCE seems to be sending an Ajax POST, so you'd need to understand how the request is being handled on your server, and in particular any URL translations performed. If it's Ajax with a json response then Joomla won't need to use a template, and some of the options in that Multiple Domains page talk about changing the template.

Comment: Hello Robbie, thank you for your answer. I have a primary domain example1.com and a secondary domain example2.com pointing to my server with a type A DNS redirection, my server accepts example2.com thanks to ServerAlias (apache).
It's exactly the same joomla for both urls (same pages, templates, etc).